# Does the HTML5 canvas rendering a browser dependent?

Tags: html5-canvas

If 2 browsers are said to be HTML5 canvas standard compliant, will there be any rendering difference between them ?.  Say I'm drawing a shape in browser 1 and 2, will the pixel by pixel comparison be equal.

Comment: I think it should be equal, but, you could try yourself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec doesn't go into as far of detail to guarantee pixel by pixel perfection.  Browsers use very different rendering libraries, and IE and Opera even offload to the GPU, so difference in implementation will undoubtedly have subtile differences in pixel shading or even some slight alignment for lines and curves.  I'm sure fonts add their own complexity.

That said, In my experience, I haven't seen any major differences that weren't attributable to missing features or bugs.

Comment: Thanks Brian Nickel for the explanation.  This gives some reasoning to my question and I'll accept this as answer